# Why is https not working for my site hosted in docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a site running in docker with 4 containers, a react front end, .net backend, sql database and nginx server. My docker compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  sssfe:
    image: mydockerhub:myimage-fe-1.3
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - sssfev:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - sssapi
  sssapi:
    image: mydockerhub:myimage-api-1.3
    environment:
      - SQL_CONNECTION=myconnection
    ports:
      - 44384:44384
    depends_on:
      - jbdatabase
  jbdatabase:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=mypass
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/opt/mssql
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
  reverseproxy:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - example_certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    links :
      - sssfe
  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - reverseproxy
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - example_certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - sssfev:/usr/share/nginx/html
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/usr/share/nginx/html --email myemail --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d example.com -d www.example.com    
volumes:
  example_certbot-etc:
    external: true
  dbdata:
  sssfev:
```

I was following [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose) and am using cerbot and letsencrypt for the certificate. My nginx conf file is this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;


        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;

        }

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        index index.html index.htm;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
        }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

My issue is that https doesn't work for my site. When I hit https://example.com, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. The non https site resolves and works fine however. Can't figure out what's going on. It looks like the ssl port is open and nginx is listening to it:

```
 ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN    
tcp     LISTEN   0        128                    *:9000                 *:*      users:(("docker-proxy",pid=18336,fd=4))
tcp     LISTEN   0        128                    *:80                   *:*      users:(("docker-proxy",pid=18464,fd=4))
tcp     LISTEN   0        128                 [::]:22                [::]:*      users:(("sshd",pid=420,fd=4))
tcp     LISTEN   0        128                    *:1433                 *:*      users:(("docker-proxy",pid=18152,fd=4))
tcp     LISTEN   0        128                    *:443                  *:*      users:(("docker-proxy",pid=18452,fd=4))
tcp     LISTEN   0        128                    *:44384                *:*      users:(("docker-proxy",pid=18243,fd=4))
```

And my containers:

```
reverseproxy   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp
sssfe          80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp       
sssapi         0.0.0.0:44384->44384/tcp                   
database       0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp
```

I'm assuming it's an issue with my nginx config, but I'm new to this and not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Run `docker exec -it reverseproxy ls -lh /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/` to see if there are any files there

Comment: yeah the certs are there

Comment: Run `docker exec -it reverseproxy curl localhost:443`

Comment: hmm, yeah, getting `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused`

Comment: Your application is not working with https. Check if images your using works with https.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to support SSL, please do this:

```
mkdir /opt/docker/nginx/conf.d -p
touch /opt/docker/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
mkdir /opt/docker/nginx/cert -p
```

then

```
vim /opt/docker/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
```

If you need to force the redirection to https when accessing http:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;  # domain
    # Pay attention to the file location, starting from /etc/nginx/ 
   
    ssl_certificate 1_www.example.com_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key 2_www.example.com.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4:!DHE;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    client_max_body_size 1024m;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #Intranet address
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.8:9090; #change it
    }
}
server {
     listen 80; 
     server_name example.com www.example.com;  # The domain name of the binding certificate
     #HTTP domain name request is converted to https
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
}
```

```
docker run -itd --name nginx -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /opt/docker/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf -v /opt/docker/nginx/cert:/etc/nginx -m 100m nginx
```

After startup, enter `docker ps` to see if the startup is successful

`docker logs nginx` view logs.

Comment: When he's using `volume`, there's no need to manually create a directory. Also he's using `docker-compose`.